# a class extend from Document ,EmbeddedDocument save failed

Tags: python, mongodb, document, mongoengine

**models.py**

```
class User(EmbeddedDocument,Document):
    ''' Store user's info'''
    user_id = IntField(unique = True)
    user_name = StringField(unique =True,primary_key =True,max_length = 256)
    user_secret = StringField(max_length=256)
```

**views.py**

```
def register(request):
    accept = False
    un = request.REQUEST.get('username')
    ps = request.REQUEST.get('password')
    if not un:
        raise ValueError('The given username must be set')
    if not ps:
        raise ValueError('The given password must be set')

    if isUserExistByName(un):
        o='The name has been registered.'
        raise TAUTHException(o)
    else:
        uid = getNextCount(UserCount)
        ps_hash = password_hash(un,ps)
        user = User(user_id = uid,user_name = un,user_secret = ps_hash)
        user.save(cascade = True)
        accept = True

    result = {'accept':accept}
    msg = urlencode(result)
    return HttpResponse(msg)
```

When I try to register a user, the program run well, but mongodb doesn't store this user. Curiously, if I change User to

```
class User(Document):
    ''' Store user's info'''
    user_id = IntField(unique = True)
    user_name = StringField(unique =True,primary_key =True,max_length = 256)
    user_secret = StringField(max_length=256)
```

It runs well and The mongodb store the user sucessful.

Answer (score 0):

See documentation: [Document](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.Document) and [EmbeddedDocument](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.EmbeddedDocument):

```
 class mongoengine.EmbeddedDocument(*args, **kwargs)
   A Document that isn’t stored in its own collection.
   EmbeddedDocuments should be used as fields on Documents through the EmbeddedDocumentField field type.
```

This because mongoengine check document type and provide different logic for different types.

But you can try use `force_insert=True` for your collection or use mixins to avoid document definition duplication:

```
class UserMixin(BaseDocument):
    ''' Store user\'s info'''
    user_id = IntField(unique = True)
    user_name = StringField(unique =True,primary_key =True,max_length = 256)
    user_secret = StringField(max_length=256)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user_name

class User(Document, UserMixin):
    pass

class UserEmbdebed(EmbeddedDocument, UserMixin):
    pass
```

Comment: UserMixin should just inherit from Object